# Является ли "наверное" в данном примере вводным словом?

Tags: вводные-слова

Наверное, поэтому я и дам тебе три желания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово "наверное" в большинстве случаев является вводным словом, так как его употребление в функции наречия ("точно", "наверняка") очень устарело ("в словах его слышался если не живописец, то уже наверное художник" (Тургенев) = "в словах его слышался если не живописец, то уж точно художник").

Вместе с тем, в данном примере это не просто вводное слово. Мы имеем дело со  сложноподчиненным предложением с неполной главной частью, которую можно восстановить только из контекста. "Наверное" является вводным словом не ко второй части предложения, а к опущенной первой (главной) части.

> По-моему, все волшебники исполняют три желания. - Наверное, [ты прав,] поэтому я и дам тебе три желания.
>
> Но ведь ты же всемогущий волшебник? - Наверное, [я всемогущий,] поэтому я и дам тебе три желания.