# «Наверное» и запятые

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставятся ли запятые после "наверное" в предложениях:
1. Наверное(,) здорово.
2. Наверное(,) пил, не знаю, давно не общались.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458807/%d0%af%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые ставятся:

1. ***Наверное***, здорово.  2. ***Наверное***,  пил, не знаю, давно не общались.

Вводно слово ***наверное*** имеет значение "по всей вероятности, вероятно, по-видимому" и практически всегда обособляется.

Необособленный вариант с другим значением считается устаревшим:

Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «точно, несомненно», «обязательно»; **устар.**): Дозволить цыганам таскаться по усадьбе – значит наверное быть обокраденным. А. Фет, Цыгане.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_426